# How to use an update query, to update a 100 of concurrent user at a time with different credentials and without lock

Tags: oracle, plsql, query-optimization

How to use an update query, to update a 100 of concurrent user at a time with different credentials and without lock.

I have  a view in my DB , which hold a ton of credentials for a list of companies.

To get a available credential id for a company_id im using a below view as:

```
   select credential_id from credential_table_v where status='Available' and company_id=100;
```

This id will be given to a api, which will then assigns to a user.

```
 procedure credential_assign(in_company_id in number
   in_credential_id out number)
   declare
   l_cred_id number;
   ....
   begin
   ........
   /* first im setting the status as blocked and then assigning the credential id to a variable*/
   update  cred_table
            set status_id      = 'blocked',
        last_modified_dt = sysdate
          where id in (select credential_id  
                       from credential_table_v 
                       where status='Available' 
                       and company_id=100 
                       and rownum=1) returning id into l_cred_id;
      -- i have specifically created rownum=1 to get one single row for a user, previously i have used group by clause and it happens that, i used to get same credential id for concurrent user 
      -- after this use of rownum=1 , i got different credentials.

    ...
    ...
    END;
    /
```

When I call the procedure, it executes in less than 1 second for a single user or two. But the same gets stuck when I call procedure in multiple threads for concurrent user.

How to avoid the lock for an update during multiple thread execution?

Comment: You cannot avoid a lock when you perform an update.Period. So if you are updating the same row from multiple sessions at the same time, they will have to wait.

Comment: Now that I look at it more, are you not just updating the same row every time? What are you trying to do from an overall perspective?

Comment: Simple, i need to get different credential to be assigned from a credential table to a user.